# Optimizing Image Retreival From App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Hie,

Designed my mobile app to work with App Engine. I have images stored as blob properties that are retreived to the app.

When getting an image, for optimization reasons, the app uses the "s=xx" suffix on the serving url to get the minimal image size.

As I understand, getting an image url this way triggers some kind of image manipulation which supposedly has
some kind of quota (according to the doc). However, in the App Engine management console, the quota detail page for the app states there isn't a quota for this operation (maybe because billing is enabled). It is counted however.

Few questions:

1. Does anyone know if in deed there is a quota for the manipulation? Is it priced? (Pricing page doesn't state there is)
2. Is using the "s=xx" suffix in real time when getting the image from thr
   serving url a good practice? Would storing thumbnails be better?
3. Is there a way for me to measure the amount of times a certain serving
   url was called and the amount of data used for serving it?

Thanks,
Lior

Answer (score 0):

> Each service request counts toward the Image Manipulation API Calls
>   quota. An app can perform multiple transformations of an image in a
>   single API call. Data sent to the service counts toward the Data Sent
>   to (Images) API quota. Data received from the Images service counts
>   toward the Data Received from (Images) API quota. Each transformation
>   of an image counts toward the Transformations Executed quota. ([source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/#Java_Quotas_and_limits))

Using `s=xx` is ok practice. Storing your own thumbnails should make sense if you need to manipulate the image beyond resize.

I am not aware of any way to know how many times the serving url was used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've ran into what you're quiting from the docs, but when I look at the console - there's no mentioning of a limit for this API. Also, there's no mentioning of it in the pricing page.

Comment: @LiorZ - it's counted but not priced as of my best knowledge beyond the network egress cost of $0.12/gb/month

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks again!

Comment: @LiorZ - happy it made sense to you.